# iPad Pro aggressively killing background apps

Tags: ipad, memory, ipados

I have an iPad Pro 10.5" running iPadOS 13.3.1.

Today I opened the Facebook app, selected a post from my notifications and started typing a comment. Switched to Safari, opened a new tab, went to a web site and copied a link from there. Switched back to Facebook to paste the link, and was surprised that the Facebook app was killed, losing the comment I was writing.

I understand apps need to be killed because of RAM limitations, but this iPad Pro has 4 GB of RAM, and by my description, it's clear I didn't do anything that should hog so much RAM as to warrant this behavior.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this aggressive killing of apps in the future?

Comment: Was the app completely killed? Apps don't run in the background so for me, if I'm using a Terminal App (Termius) and switch to Firefox/Safari to look something up, my connection is always closed.  It may have just "killed the connection"

Comment: I’ve often switched from Facebook to a different app and back without any problems, and my content remained there when I switched back, so I don’t think this is the issue.

Comment: Is it possible that Facebook crashed?  I've had that happen (not to FB..I don't use it) at various times.

Comment: It’s possible, but is there a way to distinguish between a crash and a “normal” killing due to low RAM? Perhaps if I connect it to my Mac and read the logs in Xcode?

Comment: Was it plugged in & low power mode off ? @swineone

Comment: @ankii not plugged in, but low power mode was off.

Comment: @ankii since when is low power mode a thing in an iPad? xD

Comment: The thing is...Apple is supposed to handle all the memory management.  If you're low on memory, it will close an app and write it's state to storage (as I understand it).  This is possibly what's happening.  Unfortunately, there's really nothing to tell you how much memory (not storage) you're using

Comment: It appears the issue may be more widespread: see https://www.google.com.br/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/dar3tq/ios_13_killing_background_apps_way_too/

Comment: @Allan not correct apple does not manage memory. When memory gets low apple sends a message to other apps telling them they are going to be shut down.  It is up to the app to deal with its state as the os has no idea of its state. So in this case it is upto Facebook to save  what has been written

Comment: @user151019 - wouldn't that be Apple "handling it" instead of posting an error message and making the user save data and close the app?  The point is, it's all behind the scenes.

Comment: Do you have all other apps closed in the background? Meaning that if you go into the app switcher that there are no other apps there? Do that, restart, and try again and see if it still happens.

Comment: @Allan no. Apple has no idea of what has been typed in the app. It just tells the app that it will be killed soon some apps then s a ve all their state others ignore it and lose data